# spring boot security creates folder in war

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

I added the following dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

now a folder 
"org/springframework/boot/loader"
next to my index.jsp and source folder
is created in my warfile.
It contains some compiled classes like "launcher.class", "JarLauncher.class" or "LaunchedURLClassLoader.class".

How can I tell my build not to create this folder?

Comment: you can try maven-shade-plugin  Filter property. It gives fine grained control during packaging https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer:
remove the spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```